# Coroutine wrong Behavior when scene is loaded.

Tags: unity, c#

Ok so I have this coroutine :

```
 IEnumerator ShowCharTraits()
    {

        while(!hasPlayerChosen)
        {
            yield return null;
            traitPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
        hasPlayerChosen = false;
        traitPanel.SetActive(false);
    //    Debug.Log("Got called! job done");

    }
```

It's being called like this from the awake method in my `GameManager`:

```
players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
                foreach (GameObject g in players)
                {
                    ui_Controller.StartShowCharTraits();
                    g.GetComponent<PlayerToken>().isTurn = false;
                }
```

StartShowCharTraits() is a simple method that does this :

```
  public void StartShowCharTraits()
    {
        StartCoroutine("ShowCharTraits");
    }
```

Now, I have checked the tags, no null reference exception, actually no errors or warnings are being thrown. If i load the scene in the editor and then play it everything works fine. `traitPanel.SetActive(true);` get called and my panel shows up. However when I load my scene from another scene using   `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` the above mentioned line is never reached. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok how do I explain this. I have a singleton that acts as a data holder. While developing the scene with the game manager I had attached the singleton to the gamemanger object that hold a bunch of scripts. Now when I made the main menu I ofc added my singleton to it so I can carry info to the game scene and because of this my whole game manger object was being deleted. This is the culprit from the DataHolder :

```
 void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);//This right here.

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

So I changed that line to             `Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(instance.GetType()));`